# Returning only one value from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key

I am having trouble returning only on value from a dictionary using a loop. I can't figure out how not to return unwanted values from a dictionary.

My dictionary is below. I want the user to input a book title and my code will return the corresponding ISBN.

```
library = {1234567891234: [4,'Salems Lot','Stephen King'],
       2345678912345: [1,'Pride and Prejudice','Jane Austen'],
       3456789123456: [6,'Moby Dick','Herman Melville']}


def book_search():
    book_title = input("What book are you searching for? ")
    for k, v in library.items():
        if v[1].lower() == book_title:
            print("The ISBN of", book_title, "is", k)
        else:
            print("This book is not in the library")
```

But my program returns all values in the dictionary. How can I get it to just return the specific ISBN? Below is what I get currently.

```
What book are you searching for? salems lot
The ISBN of salems lot is 1234567891234
This book is not in the library
This book is not in the library
```

Could I get some help with this please?

Comment: If you don't want it to print in the case that the title doesn't match, why do you explicitly print in the case that the title doesn't match?

Comment: As well as what @jon has said - if you're going to be doing that lookup a lot, you should consider creating a reverse mapping of title->other_info...

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is an excellent point. I do not need to do that. I just need to implement some exception handling. Thank you

Comment: Create a flag boolean at the start and set it to False. When the item you want has been found change it to True and break the for loop using the 'break' keyword. Then instead of printing this book is not in the library each time, outside of the loop just write - if flag == False: print(''This book is not in the library")

Comment: @Crawley that's not a very idiomatic way of doing it. Normally you'd use the `for: ... else: ...` structure, or have an early `return` in the positive case and then put the "not found" logic *outside* the loop.

Comment: You don't need exception handling, just delete the `else:` part.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a loop to search for an entry, you should exit the loop while it has been found. And consider it's not existed only after the loop (not in every iteration).

The following code should work:

```
library = {1234567891234: [4, 'Salems Lot', 'Stephen King'],
           2345678912345: [1, 'Pride and Prejudice', 'Jane Austen'],
           3456789123456: [6, 'Moby Dick', 'Herman Melville']}


def book_search():
    book_title = input("What book are you searching for? ")
    found = False
    for k, v in library.items():
        if v[1].lower() == book_title.lower():
            print("The ISBN of", book_title, "is", k)
            # We have already found a match, so should exit of the loop.
            found = True
            break

    if not found:
        print("This book is not in the library")


book_search()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confused between `print` and `return`.

`print`, as its name implies, will show the argument on your prompt.

`return` will stop the function and will get out of the function the value you're sending into `return`.

Here, if you simply change `print` by `return`, and if you'd just call your function such as...

```
# Instead of "book_search()", do...
print book_search()
```

You would have the asked behavior.

- Your `else` condition might be at a bad scope. I believe you might want it in some other space.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem:

`

```
  library = {1234567891234: [4,'Salems Lot','Stephen King'], 2345678912345: [1,'Pride and Prejudice','Jane Austen'], 3456789123456: [6,'Moby Dick','Herman Melville']} 


 def book_search(): 

    j=0

    book_title = input("What book are you searching for? ") 
    for k, v in library.items():
           if v[1].lower() == book_title:
                j=j+1
                print("The ISBN of", book_title, "is", k)
    if(j==0)
            print("This book is not in the library")`
```